# screenGrab() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, procedural-programming

I've written the following:

```
screenState = screenGrab(workingDirectory + '/Screenshots')
```

Which calls this subroutine:

```
def screenGrab(directory):
    """
    Takes a screenshot of an area of the screen.

    :params:
        directory : directory to save screenshot in
    """

    box = (x_pad + 1, y_pad + 1, x_pad + 961, y_pad + 641)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    im.save(directory + '/full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) + '.png', 'PNG')
```

And when I attempt to run the code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: screenGrab() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I'm unsure as to why this error is occurring.

Comment: Dude, is `screenGab()` a function or a class you are calling/initializing? your function signature doesn't match at all.

Comment: Sorry, I'll give the full definition.

Comment: Have you redefined screenGrab anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Right, stupid error. Turns out I had two files with the same name with the same function (one was a .pyw and the other a .py) the import was calling the wrong file.